# VBA code to extract text from a text file that matches the following pattern #{pqfn:format('<TEXT TO EXTRACT>')

Tags: excel, vba

For Eg.

I have following file data

```
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText  value="#{pqfn:format('FILENAME')}" /></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{file.file.notes}"/>
</t:column>
<t:column>
<br></br><h:outputText value="#{pqfn:format('INVALID_DEALER_CODE')}"/>
                                                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText  value="#{pqfn:format('STATUS')}" /></f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{bm:getStatusText(file)}"/>
                                            </t:column>
                                            <t:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText  value="#{pqfn:format('PERIOD')}" /></f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText rendered="#{file.status == 0}" value="#{pqfn:formatPeriod(file.period)}"/>
                                            </t:column>
                                            <t:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText  value="#{pqfn:format('DEALER')}" /></f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText rendered="#{file.status == 0}" value="#{file.networkEntity.name}"/>
                                            </t:column>
                                            <t:column align="left">
                                                <f:facet name="header">&#160;</f:facet>
                                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{file.status != 0}" value="#{file.processed}" id="process"/>
                                                <h:outputLabel for="process" value="#{pqfn:format('PROCESS')}" />
                                            </t:column>
                                        </t:dataTable>
                                    </td>`enter code here`
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="height:40px">
                                        <h:commandButton action="#{submissions.processDmsFiles}" value="#{pqfn:format('PROCESS')}" disabled="#{! submissions.someProcessed}" styleClass="form-button" />
                                        &#160;
                                        <h:commandButton action="#{submissions.dmsImport}" value="#{pqfn:format('CANCEL')}" immediate="true" styleClass="form-button" />
                                    </td>
```

And I need following values as output in a separate excel sheet

FILENAME
INVALID_DEALER_CODE
STATUS
PERIOD
DEALER
PROCESS

and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Please, fix lines indentations.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (but its one search output per line):

```
Sub Search()

 Const strFileName = "C:\User\YourTextfile.txt" 'Textfile path
 Const strSearch = "'" 'Textfile search char
 Dim strLine As String
 Dim f As Integer
 Dim lngLine As Long
 Dim char1Pos As Integer
 char1Pos = 1
 Dim char2Pos As Integer
 Dim strText As String
 f = FreeFile
 Open strFileName For Input As #f
 Do While Not EOF(f)
     lngLine = lngLine + 1
     Line Input #f, strLine
     If InStr(char1Pos, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

        char1Pos = InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare)
        char2Pos = InStr(char1Pos + 1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare)

        strText = Mid(strLine, char1Pos + 1, (char2Pos - char1Pos) - 1)
        Debug.Print strText

    End If
 Loop
 Close #f

End Sub
```